# killing zombie folder `Ubuntu One`

Tags: ubuntu-one

I deleted my `Ubuntu One` folder and rebooted but the folder came back. How can I kill this zombie folder?

Edit: Because there were suggestions that I uninstall Ubuntu One, I must add that I want to use Ubuntu One.  The folder appears to be related to sharing.  I will not be sharing from this machine and I don't want a folder that I will not be using soon.

Comment: Have you tried removing the application 'Ubuntu One' first and then deleting that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all ubuntuone packages installed in your system. Otherwise, the program would be launching again in each reboot and creating the folder again.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu One folder is used by Ubuntu One.

It's not related to sharing, it's the folder that Ubuntu One will sync across your devices. That's why if you remove this folder, Ubuntu One will recreate it.